# Blue line appears on the side of liquid after render

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I can see an unusual blue line on the side of the liquid inside a cup after render. I cannot understand how to remove it. Check image:
[image]
Notice the liquid carefully, you will notice a blue line in it.
Please guide the steps to remove it, if possible.

Comment: Please use the builtin tools to upload images. [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line is a natural glass rim reflection.

To eliminate it, you can increase Roughness and change IOR for your liquid material.

Or you can uncheck Glossy Ray Visibility for the cup object.

In both cases, the glass/coffee material won't be physically accurate anymore.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is IQR? As I am new to Blender I don't know it's full form. I will rather uncheck Glossy ray visibility.

Comment: Sorry, I misspelled it. It is IOR (index of refraction value). You can change it as any other value in the Principled Shader (see my first image)